# How to Calculate Android Device Battery Capacity?

Tags: java, android, batterymanager

Currently, I am working on an Android project for which I need to get the device's Battery Capacity. This function retrieves battery percentage and remaining battery current from BatteryManager and then calculates Maximum capacity (mAh). But I need to get the Battery capacity that the manufacturer claims.

Example:

> My device's battery capacity is 4900 mAh (As per the manufacturer),
> but this function returns 4600 mAh. I need to get that 4900 mAh.

```
public long getBatteryCapacity(Context context) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {            
        BatteryManager mBatteryManager = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE);
        
        Long chargeCounter = mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CHARGE_COUNTER);
        Long capacity = mBatteryManager.getLongProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);

        if (chargeCounter != null && capacity != null) {
            long value = (long) (((float) chargeCounter / (float) capacity) * 100f);
            return value;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not going to work.  First off, you're going to have rounding errors.  None of this stuff is exact.  Secondly, you're assuming that the capacity of the battery as reported by the manufacturer and the capacity of the battery Android treats as 100% are the same.  They may be, but they don't have to be- Android might decide to treat 90% of battery as full, so it has the remaining 10% for emergency power/shutdown/battery maintenance (some batteries are physically harmed if actually run to 0).  Or it may reserve power to account for environmental conditions (batteries work differently depending on temperature, for example).  4900 from the manufacturer is the maximum amount of charge under optimal conditions, not an actual useful number.  Its only value is in direct comparison to another battery of the same technology.

Comment: Ok, Got it. Is there any way that I can get the exact number provided by the manufacturer?